# Self-signed certificate error with custom S3 server with AWS SDK Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

I'm trying to connect to custom S3 server (not AWS based) and create bucket.

Using following code in Python works:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
s3res = session.resource(service_name='s3',
  use_ssl=True,
  verify=False,
  aws_access_key_id='xxx',
  aws_secret_access_key='xxx',
  endpoint_url='https://xxx',
  config=botocore_client_config)
```

However, following code in Node.js does not:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const https = require('https');

const S3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: 'xxx',
  secretAccessKey: 'xxx',
  endpoint: 'https://xxx/',
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  httpOptions: {
    agent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })
  }
});
```

Actually, it results in following error when trying to create bucket:

```
{ NetworkingError: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:109:11)
    at Object.request (http.js:41:10)
    at features.constructor.handleRequest (/home/ec2-user/s3-tests/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:42:23)
```

If I remove custom https agent, I get following error:

```
{ Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1048:34)
```

Moreover, setting `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` does not help.

Comment: According to these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#constructor_details), it says for the httpOptions.agent option: _agent [http.Agent, https.Agent] — the Agent object to perform HTTP requests with. Used for connection pooling. Defaults to the global agent (http.globalAgent) for non-SSL connections. Note that for SSL connections, a special Agent object is used in order to enable peer certificate verification. This feature is only available in the Node.js environment._ Perhaps there is some custom code validating certificates?

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you specified `agent` in `httpOptions`, you used `https`:

```
const https = require('https');
```

If you don't want the ssl version, use `http` instead:

```
const http = require('http');

const S3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: 'xxx',
  secretAccessKey: 'xxx',
  endpoint: 'https://xxx/',
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  httpOptions: {
    agent: new http.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the node version is missing the `sslEnabled: false` from the S3 options...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import * as https from 'https';

import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { NodeHttpHandler } from '@aws-sdk/node-http-handler';

const client = new S3Client({
  // other options ...
  requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }),
  }),
});
```

And do your request with client